# How does java AsynchronousFileChannel work if the kernel not support AIO

Tags: java, linux, aio

I have 2 questions

1. How will AsynchronousFileChannel work if my operating system does not support AIO (lower then linux 2.6 etc).
2. How to append sth into AsynchronousFileChannel, as far as I know AsynchronousFileChannel only supports write(ByteBuffer, long position, A attachment, CompletionHandler handler) and write(ByteBuffer src, long position) both need a position param. Should I count the position myself?

Comment: "I have 2 questions" -- then *ask* two questions, don't put them in one question.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2: From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html)

> An asynchronous file channel does not have a current position within
>   the file. Instead, the file position is specified to each read and
>   write method that initiates asynchronous operations.

So yes, you need to keep track of the position yourself.